# Seeking Article "Generating random lattices according to the invariant distribution" by M. Ajtai

Tags: reference-request, lattices

I am searching for a specific article titled "Generating random lattices according to the invariant distribution" authored by Ajtai. Despite being widely cited in various papers, I have been unable to locate it on platforms such as Google Scholar and dblp. The article is of particular interest due to its relevance to my research, and I am keen to access its contents. Could anyone provide me with information regarding the publication details or a reliable source where I can find this article? Any assistance in obtaining this article or insights into its content would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One approach (I think the most likely to work) might be to email people who give early citations of the paper (eg in the mid-2000s), in case they still have a copy. I note that Ajtai published https://doi.org/10.1145/237814.237838 in 1996, with a similar title, as well as this longer preliminary version (with an addendum) https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/eccc-reports/1996/TR96-007/index.html.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to contact several authors but unfortunately did not receive a response. Perhaps I should try more.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't know if Ajtai is likely to respond to an email, but he's still alive as far as I can tell, and published something as recently as 2022. Other than that, try some recent co-authors of his if they can put you in touch with him.

Answer (score 0):

Professor Ajtai kindly sent me a pdf of the unpublished paper (77 pages). I am not sure that I can post it publicly, just write me an email < beenakker@ilorentz.org > and I will forward it to you.

[image]